# Appium - How to Validate if an object exists

Tags: android, appium

I'm new to this forum and appium/android automation, I need help on verifying if an object exists on my app before I take the next action.

I tried using the following code below but is not even reaching my second print statement.

```
@Test
public void addContact() {
    System.out.println( "Checking if Contact exists.... 111111 ");
   
    WebElement e = driver.findElement(By.name("John Doe"));
           
    System.out.println( "Checking if Contact exists.... 222222");
   
    boolean contactExists = e.isDisplayed();
   
    System.out.println( contactExists );
   
   
    if (contactExists == true) {          
        System.out.println( "Contact exists.... ");           
    } else {           
        System.out.println( "Contact DOES NOT exists.... ");
    }
 }
```

Running this code here's appium console output... it just keeps looping through this and script fails.

> info: [BOOTSTRAP] [info] Got command of type ACTION
>
> info: [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: find
>
> info: [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Finding John Doe using NAME with the contextId:
>
> info: [BOOTSTRAP] [info] Returning result: {"value":"No element found","status":7}
>
> info: Pushing command to appium work queue: ["find",{"strategy":"name","selector":"John Doe","context":"","multiple":false}]
>
> info: [BOOTSTRAP] [info] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"find","params":{"strategy":"name","selector":"John Doe","context":"","multiple":false}}

is isDisplayed the right approach here or is there a better alternative to do this?

Cheers.... TIA

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Appium 1.0+

- By.name locating strategy has been deprecated.Please use some other stuffs like By.xpath etc.

Answer (score 1):

In the newer version of appium you have "accessibility id".Use these instead.
Happy automating

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following will help you. I have the methods in my TestBase class:

```
    protected static boolean isElementPresent(By by) {
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(by);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    if (list.size() == 0) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return list.get(0).isDisplayed();
    }

}

public boolean elementIsNotPresent(By by) {
    try {
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        return driver.findElements(by).isEmpty();
    } finally {
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}
```

Also, I use the following code to wait until some certain element on the screen:

```
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By
            .xpath("//android.widget.Button[contains(@text, 'Log In')]")));
```

or:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By
            .xpath("//android.widget.TextView[contains(@resource-id, 'action_bar_title')]")));
```